# How can i still get the data between two Datetime based on your current_date?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So i have data in my database which look like this.

```
id | value|  current_date |            time           | group
1      0      2020-03-30        2020-03-30 19:00:00       2
2      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-30 20:00:00       2
3      10     2020-03-30        2020-03-30 21:00:00       2 
4      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-30 22:00:00       2
5      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-30 23:00:00       2
6      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 00:00:00       2
7      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 01:00:00       2
8      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 02:00:00       2
9      5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 03:00:00       2
10     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 04:00:00       2
11     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 05:00:00       2
12     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 06:00:00       2
13     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 07:00:00       2
14     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 08:00:00       2
15     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 09:00:00       2
16     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 10:00:00       2
17     5      2020-03-30        2020-03-31 11:00:00       2
```

My goal is to get all data that is between 7PM - 12NOON.

In my php code i am passing a parameter which is the current_date(Assume that today is March 30) for this day. So that i can put it on my where clause in my database query.

```
$shift_date = '';

$shift_date = ($shift_date != '') ?
            DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $shift_date, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila')) :
            DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date("Y-m-d"), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));

$current_hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $shift_date->format('Y-m-d') .' 19:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila')); 

//2020-03-30 19:00:00
```

And this is my query, with this query i have no problem on getting the data because it is still March 30.

```
SELECT value,time,current_date,group
FROM table
WHERE time >='2020-03-30 19:00:00' AND time <= DATE_ADD("2020-03-30 19:00:00", INTERVAL 16 HOUR)
AND group = 2;
```

The dilema that i am having is what if the date gets to `2020-03-31 :00:00:00` then this line of code in my php will have a value of `2020-03-31: 19:00:00` then i will not already get the data that i want.

```
$shift_date = '';

$shift_date = ($shift_date != '') ?
            DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $shift_date, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila')) :
            DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date("Y-m-d"), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));

$current_hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $shift_date->format('Y-m-d') .' 19:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila')); 

//2020-03-31 19:00:00
```

I should still get the data that i need between the March 30 7PM - March 31 11 noon. I am really stuck
with this problem that i have. Thank you for all the advance help that will give me time to help me on this.

Comment: Hi, I'm confused with your question. Shouldn't $shift_date have the date you want, so if it's always the current date then shouldn't you just set it back to when it should be.
Sorry I'm really confused.

Comment: Side note: `time <= addtime(time, 10000)` will always be true unless `time` is `NULL`.

Comment: @RichardHousham Hi sir! thank you for the time, the shift_date is always changing based on the date for this day.

Comment: @stickybit ah yes your right because your are just adding time to time and so it's always going to be less!

Comment: @RichardHousham what should i need to do sir on my logic so that i can achieve the goal that i am thinking.

Comment: sorry but I can't really make any sense out of the problem and what an adequate answer would be. Is the problem that you always want the results between a certain time irrelevant of the date?

Answer (score -1):

Hi i know my question is really confusing, but i already solve it.

the end time is always 11PM so i just need to -12 hours so i can fetch all data base on the `current_date` in my database;

```
$shift_date = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$shift_date->modify("-12 hours");
```